# Is sprouting an example of an axonal or dendritic mechanism of synaptic plasticity?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, plasticity

Hi I am having trouble wrapping my head around the mechanisms of synaptic plasticity which include

1. Sprouting
2. Rerouting
3. Pruning

I have read conflicting sources of information, some suggesting that sprouting involves axons sprouting and is therefore axonal and also involves dendrites branching out.

I have also seen sources saying that sprouting only refers to the axon and dendrites branching out and extending is something distinct.

Rerouting is essentially the formation of a new neural pathway.

It would be great if someone could clarify the sprouting mechanism for me, and which mechanisms are dendritic, axonal or both.

Comment: Where are you reading about sprouting (cite your sources)? Why do you need to classify a mechanism as "axonal" or "dendritic" (what's your goal)?

Comment: https://www.krigolsonteaching.com/uploads/4/3/8/4/43848243/nilsen_article.pdf
"Neuronal plasticity mediated by sprouting can involve alteration in dendritic spine"

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/sprout
"Dendrites sprout only after axon begins projection"

https://www.nature.com/articles/282506a0?error=cookies_not_supported&code=6279fe48-e74a-4d88-b7d4-f3cc8803c35a

"Sprouting can occur in two ways: from axon terminals (terminal sprouting) or from the intramuscular axons themselves, probably from the nodes of Ranvier (collateral sprouting)"

Comment: @BryanKrause Above are my sources, and the reason why I'm needing to classify it is (im in hs atm) and if a question was asking 'sketch sprouting' or something, I don't know whether or not I would include dendrites expanding as part of the diagram.

Comment: I don't think that sounds like a very productive study strategy. Aside from perhaps usage in some subfields, it does not appear to me that "sprouting" is specific terminology. Expect each user to define it.